# How to configure XCode to create proper application bundle

Tags: xcode, macos, bundle

I have a project which I have created in Xcode (starting with the command-line tool template) and I need to create a standard .app application bundle so I can use that to create the installer with PackageMaker.

Currently the only thing listed under 'Products' is the main binary, and when I try to create an archive I get a non-standard directory structure (../usr/local/bin/...) instead of ../Contents/MacOS.

I also noticed under Packaging that 'Wrapper Extension' is set to blank rather than '.app'.

I think my project is not configured to create an application bundle, however from what I read online Xcode is supposed to automatically create an application bundle when you use one of the standard templates. What setting(s) do I need to change in order to generate a proper .app file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode's command line tool templates do not create application bundles. Only the project templates that use the Cocoa and Cocoa Touch frameworks create application bundles. You will have to add another target to your project to create a .app bundle. I have no experience wrapping a command-line tool inside a Cocoa program so I can't help you with that.